# C++ , how do i get a particular string in a html code

Tags: c++, wget

I am trying to parse [this XML Yahoo feed](http://sg.finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote).

How do i like get each record into an array in C++
like create a structure

then got those variable 
and record each element inside the structure.

In the first place, how do i get the value out

Thanks

Comment: C++ has `std::string::find()` and `std::string::substr()`. You can use these to locate and extract the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mess with html code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
  std::ifstream ifile("in.html");
  std::string line;
  std::string ndl("<span id=\"yfs_l10_sgdmyr=x\">");
  while(ifile.good()){ 
    getline(ifile, line);
    if (line.size()) {
      size_t spos, epos;
      if ((spos = line.find(ndl)) != std::string::npos) {
        spos += ndl.size();
        if ((epos = line.find(std::string("</span>"), spos)) != std::string::npos) {
          std::cout << line.substr(spos, epos-spos) << std::endl;
        }   
      }   
    }   
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have the in.html file?

Comment: i was parsing this page [link](http://sg.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=USDSGD=X) , i use lynx -source URL > buffer.txt , then the buffer is actually the source code. i changed your sgdmyr to usdsgd, but seems doesnt work

Answer (score 5):

You may want to see if the given page offers output in a JSON format.  Then you can simply request the value instead of messing around with HTML.  The Yahoo! Finance site may even offer an API that you can use to easily request the value.

Comment: I found the api, but how do i parse this to get e.g USD/SGD